# Alamofire parameters json format bug

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have this helper function to create the json to pass as parameter along with my PUT request.

```
static func helperProfileParametersWith(user: User?, username: String?, email: String?, meta_motto: String?, meta_status: String?) -> [String: AnyObject] {
    if let user = user {
        return ["username": username ?? "", "email": email ?? "", "status": user.status ?? "", "meta": ["status": meta_status ?? "", "motto": meta_motto ?? ""], "type":user.type ?? ""]
    }
    return [String:AnyObject]()
}
```

The output will like

```
{
  username: "admin", 
  email: "xx@xx.xx", 
  status: "banned",
  meta: {
    status: "I am happy today",
    motto: "i love coding"
  }
}
```

Then I pass the parameter to the function

```
static func updateUserProfile(userId: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject], failure: ((NSError)->Void)?, success: ([String: AnyObject], Set<String>)->Void) {

    Alamofire.request(.PUT, API.baseUrl + API.user.fetchUpdateProfile + "/" + userId, parameters: parameters).responseJSON {
        response in
    }
}
```

But from my NodeJS server, what I get is

```
{
  username: "admin", 
  email: "xx@xx.xx", 
  status: "banned",
  meta["status"]: "I am happy today",
  meta["motto"]: "i love coding"
}
```

As you can see the sub dictionary is "flattened", the key becomes `meta["motto"]` string, instead of `meta`, then `motto`

I am pretty sure it's not the problem with my server, because my Angular client works fine.

Note: In case you are curious. I use `ng-resource` to send the JSON in correct format.

```
app.factory('Profile', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource(constant.webapi.user.fetchUpdateProfile, {profileId: '@_id'}, {
        update: {method: 'PUT'}
    })
}])



$scope.updateProfile = function() {
    $scope.profile.$update(function(data) {
        data = helper.dataAppendedWithMessage(data, 'success', 'success update profile')
        $scope.profile = data
        helper.showMessage($scope, data, false)
    },
        //helper.callbackToShowMessage($scope, false)
        function(err) {
            //Note: if fail to update, reload the page.
            //Otherwise we have to revert back to original, which is tedious to do
            helper.showMessage($scope, err.data, true) //since we reload the page, store message in $cookies
            $window.location.reload(true)
        })
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is the problem? Is it that your `meta` parameter is not displayed the same way in Swift and Node?

Comment: @LaurentRivard the sub dictionary is "flattened", `meta["motto"]` becomes a string. What I want is the original structure (`dictionary inside a dictionary")

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're sending the Content-Type "application/json" along with your Alamofire request.